# neo4j: how to import data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, import, neo4j

I have  5 tables: 3 for nodes and 2 for relationships between them ( relationship = child). How to transfer the data from Oracle to neo4j ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Neo4j site has an entire documentation section on [moving data from relational databases to neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/).  There are a bunch of different possibilities.

The simplest way though is to use your chosen database tools to export your tables to a CSV format, and then to use Cypher's [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) command to pull the data in.

The data can't be directly transferred though, in the sense that your tables represent entities and relationships between them; when moving the data to neo4j, this requires that you consider [what you want your graph data model to look like](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/).

Because the flexibility and the power that neo4j will give you will ultimately have a lot to do with how you modeled your data, you should give this careful consideration before you dump the CSV and try to import it into neo4j.